# ffmpeg overlay image on video loses quality and sticks - any alternatives?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I need a better way to overlay images on video. Currently I am using  this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -shortest -loop 1 -i 57982344.png -filter_complex "[1:v]fade=t=in:st=5:d=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1[over];[0:v][over]overlay=0:0 " -c:v libx264 -crf 23 output.mp4
```

Sometimes the video loses quality; sometimes the video is stuck for 1 to 2 sec but after that work well, so it feels  unreliable.

Comment: *"Questions seeking **product, service, or learning material recommendations** are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. [Here are a few suggestions](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/) on how to properly ask this type of question. "* Why is `ffmpeg` unsuitable? We need more details, both to be able to asnwer the question and for it to be on-topic.

Comment: That edit helps :) Does `ffmpeg` give any errors or warning messages while processing?

Comment: not its not giving any error

Comment: Can you give more info on the problems? For quality, does decreasing the `crf` value (ie more quality) help? When does the video 'stick' ?

Comment: You should provide the complete console output from the command.

Comment: ok just tell me how i get good quality output while using  libx264

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different codec? I've been frustrated with similar issues during the past two days and libx264 was the culprit.

Here's what you could try, and you can always re-encode into .mp4 later:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -shortest -loop 1 -i 57982344.png -filter_complex "[1:v]fade=t=in:st=5:d=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1[over];[0:v][over]overlay=0:0 " -crf 23 -vcodec huffyuv output.avi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/video/nsm.mp4 -i \
 /storage/emulated/0/saved_images/image.png -preset ultrafast \
 -strict -2 -filter_complex overlay=x=228:y=231:enable='between(t,3,13)' \
 /storage/emulated/0/video/outputxy.mp4
```

Comment: would it be possible to add more explanation?

Comment: stick video stuck where its inserted